# Result of javascript regular expression not understood

Tags: javascript, regex

When I eval (in javascript) [I meant, used string.match()]:

```
<!--:es-->Text number 1<!--:--><!--:en-->text 2<!--:-->
```

using

```
/<!--:es-->(.|\n)*?<!--:-->/
```

I get as match:

```
Text number 1,1
```

I mean, it adds a comma and repeats the last character. Does anybody know why this happens?

PS. text could have carriage return, that is why i used `(.|\n).`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with Javascript's regex options, but I don't believe you need the `|\n` part of your expression, `.` should match any character, including newline (unless javascript turns that option off by default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of a regular expression match is an array.

The zero-th element of the array is the whole match : "Text number 1"
The first element of the array is the contents of the first group, in this case "1" since the * is outside the parentheses.

When the array is converted to a string, you get the contents with commas in between.

Comment: Unless you can't turn singleline mode off in javascript, you should be able to exclude the `|\n` (and therefore, the group) entirely, to fix this problem.

Comment: @Jeff, if you want to exclude the group, you can use a non-capturing group using the `(?:...)` syntax.  `/<!--:es-->(?:.|\n)*?<!--:-->/`

Answer (score 2):

> When I eval (in javascript)

Don't. [Use RegExp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Eval() evaluates any ECMAScript, you don't want to do this if you don't have 100% control over the input.

Comment: When i said eval i was reffering to string.match(/xxxx/)

Answer (score 0):

Some research has shown me that the `.` can't match newlines in javascript.

I'd rewrite your regex this way:

`/<!--:es-->[\s\S]*?<!--:-->/`

This will avoid the problem you saw, as it excludes the capture group.

And ghoppe is right: use RegExp.